# Indirect Measurement of a tower without similar triangles

Tags: trigonometry

I was asked to measure the height of an object indirectly. I am not allowed to use similar triangles and am not allowed to use shadows for proportions. I have to measure the tower from 11 inches away in any direction. I have a ruler and protractor as tools. I am allowed to measure the length of a popsicle stick and try to estimate the angle of elevation from the ground to the top of the object. Does anyone have a theory on how to solve this?

Comment: If you can measure the angle and know the distance from the object, can't you use basic trigonometry? Also is the information that the object is a Popsicle stick tower relevant?

Comment: Given the restrictions imposed, he surely can't use trig, since trig depends heavily on similar triangles.

Comment: @Mark Fischler so do you think there is any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Strange question, with a lot of arbitrary rules. Almost impossible to give an answer because information is most likely missing on what is and isn't allowed.
Exactly how does the tower even look?

I guess one way of "solving" it would be taking a stick, measuring it with a ruler (if that's allowed I don't know); then you estimate the overlap/distance of/between the vertical sticks. After that just multiply the number of sticks $n$ by the length of a stick, then remove $n-1$ times the length of the overlap from that sum (or add $n-1$ times the length of the distance between sticks to that sum).

Comment: I have edited the post to show more rules. Hopefully, this is more helpful.